# Python Queue doesn't contain all resultset data from SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing

I originally thought I was incorrectly passing data to my subprocesses so I asked a question [How do I pass object data to other Python multiprocessing processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574908/how-do-i-pass-object-data-to-other-python-multiprocessing-processes?noredirect=1#comment80103557_46574908). It got closed for a duplicate but after more research on the issue and implementing a Queue per the other links provided I don't think that is the problem.

Part of the data is making it to my process, a few of the other parts are not which are what I assume part of SQLAlchemy objects.

What was put into the Queue:

[image: Data going into the Queue]

What I see in my process getting out of Queue:

[image: Processing receiving end of Queue]

So I believe the issue comes down to SQLAlchemy and its states. How can I pass a SQLAlchemy resultset to a process without it losing all of this data?

The sample code.

```
def test_mp(queue):
    while True:
        file = queue.get(True)

results = dbsession.query(Raw_records).limit(10).all()

inqueue = mp.Queue()
for item in results:
    inqueue.put(item)
pool = mp.Pool(4, test_mp, (inqueue,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

edit: figured out the "drill_parameters_record" highlight why it isn't returning.

Had to do `.options(joinedload(Raw_records.drill_parameters_record))`

But the raw_xml column is still blank. It is a custom type so it is an object. I used this to create it. [SQLAlchemy declaring custom UserDefinedType for XML in MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333410/sqlalchemy-declaring-custom-userdefinedtype-for-xml-in-mssql)

Comment: `multiprocessing.Queue` requires objects to be picklable, and `lxml.etree._ElementTree` [does not appear to be picklable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274438).

Comment: @univerio ahhh. That makes sense. I guess I'll just convert it to a string, and then convert it back to an lxml object afterwords.